# What's the best way to save and restore a MapView in Android?

Tags: android

I have a `MapActivity` that contains a `MapView` with some custom controls, state information, and an `ItemizedOverlay` composed by some locations that I draw using the default approach (using `populate()`, `super.draw()` and `createItem()`) and by some lines that I draw in the overrided `draw()` method.

So, when the activity is paused, I have to save:

1. Some state information
2. The ItemizedOverlay
3. [Maybe more Overlays in the future.]

I'm saving the state information as usual, putting them in the bundle. I'm thinking in doing the same with the `Overlays`, implementing `Parcelable`in  each one of the `OverlayItems` and so, but I don't know if there is a better way to store the complete state of the `MapViews`.

The information depends on remote requests that I don't want to repeat each time the activity is paused.

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

If all information regarding `OverlayItems` is obtained from remote request, the most simple solution would be to store last request output in a file.

On activity restart, you check if the cashed request output is available (and perhaps is still valid for your needs) and than use the existing methods to extract data from it.

For example, if you get POI's from remote KML or JSON, you can use the existing parser to extract data from local file as well.

Comment: Yes, it's a good solution when you want to preserve the state for a long time. But our problem was with other cases in which `onPause` is called as orientation changes and so.

Answer (score 0):

As general solution `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` with the complete `Activity` or with an array with the `Objects` of interest can be used. Then in `onCreate()` the `View` can be regenerated.